# Recommenderlab error unable to find inherited method

Tags: r, recommendation-engine, recommenderlab

I'm a newbie in R and need some advice with recommenderlab.

I have a "training" dataset comprised of 6 variables, and the first line looks like this:

```
              song_id                                  user_id     title release               artist_name year
3  SOAAAGQ12A8C1420C8 384e068d83822096b2ef9a35ba520d97a8f74741 Orgelblut Dolores Bohren & Der Club Of Gore 2008
```

I'm trying to use recommenderlab to use UBCF,  and use the following code:

```
rec <- Recommender("train", method = "UBCF")
```

But get this error

> Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  :   unable to find an
>   inherited method for function ‘Recommender’ for signature
>   ‘"character"’

Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

train should be your training data, not a string. Can you try this:

`rec <- Recommender(train, method = "UBCF")`